# C# - Toggle hidden files system wide?

Tags: c#, file, toggle, directory, hidden

What would be the best way to be able to toggle hidden folder and files system wide?  I would prefer to do it in C#.  I know I would use the global keyboard hook but I am not sure how I would toggle folders/files to be hidden and then visible when the shortcut key is pressed.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unhide it with the registry:

```
User Key: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\
Advanced]
Value Name: Hidden
Data Type: REG_DWORD (DWORD Value)
Value Data: (1 = show hidden, 2 = do not show)
```

Then send a SHChangeNotify event to the desktop.